# stop refreshing the farpoint spread sheet

Tags: vb.net, farpoint-spread

I have a problem with farpoint spread sheet, that while loading the data into the spread sheet, the sheet refreshes each time a value is set.

I have large number of rows and columns so, the sheet take quite large time till loading.

any idea how to disable the refresh and enable it again after the data is completely loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got it, just suspend the layout of the spreadsheet, then resume after executing your code.

```
FpSpread.SuspendLayout()

' your code

FpSpread.ResumeLayout(True)
```